# Linear operator with eigenvalues 1 that permutes a generating set

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm trying to solve the following problem,

Let $T:V\to V$ be a linear operator on the finite dimensional vector space $V$ over $\mathbb{C}$. Suppose that all the eigenvalues of $T$ are $1$, and that $T$ permutes a set $S$ that generates $V$. Show that $T=id_V$.

I solved the problem for the case where $S$ is finite. In this case, $T^k=id_V$ where $k=|S|!$; since the minimal polynomial of $T$ is of the form $(x-1)^m$ and divides $ x^k-1$, then $m=1$ and the result follows.

How can I prove the general case?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As currently formulated, the assertion is wrong because you can just take $T$ with minimal polynomial $(x-1)^2$ and $S=V$. Clearly $T$ permutes $S$...

Comment: Basically that $T$ permutes a generating set is not a condition since any operator permutes $V$. Thus the assertion says that if all eigenvalues are $1$, then the operator is the identity. This is clearly false.

Comment: In conclusion, we need to impose the condition that $S$ is finite.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, it suffices to impose that the complement of $S$ properly contains a subspace of codimension $1$. This is slightly weaker than finite.